# HSSFWorkbook, maximum textlength of cell, cropped after 700 words

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I am trying  to save text information into a cell

```
    for(int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
        for(int j = 0; j < columns.get(i).length; j++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell((short)j);
            cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(columns.get(i)[j]));
        }           
    }
```

the information I want to save is truncated/cropped in the exported excel file, approximately after 980 chars.

My stylesheet looks like:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Alerts");
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor( IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex() );
style.setFillPattern( CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
sheet.autoSizeColumn(25000);
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
```

Comment: Don't you want to be auto-sizing the columns you put your data into, rather than some random column # `25000` ?

Comment: Can you craft and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also are you sure about 700 words / 980 chars (small words IMHO)?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have added sheet.autoSizeColumn(25000); to try if it works with a fixed size of a column length. Without out the problem also exist.

Comment: The defined max length is 32767, see https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html, as stated above maybe you can reduce your code to the bare minimum to show the problem and post that to make it easier for others to reproduce/analyze your problem.

Comment: As explained in the javadocs, [the argument to Sheet.autoSizeColumn(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29) specifies which column to size, so you are currently trying to size column `25000` which is unlikely to be what you want!